# Writing script that runs on Windows and Mac

Tags: windows, macos, perl

I need to write a small script that renames some files in a directory. This script needs to be run on Mac and Windows.

What is the best scripting language for this? I want to write something that runs just by calling it and there is no need to install anything else.

For example, writing a Perl script and compiling it to run on Windows and then compiling it to run on Mac. Can I do this?

Any other, more elegant solution?

Comment: You could try writing a command.com/powershell/vbscript and bash/perl/python polyglot but there not much you can do on windows with just the base install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing matches your criteria. You will need to install something (e.g. `perl`) if you want something that runs on both systems.

If you had `perl` on both systems, you could indeed write a program that runs on both. You wouldn't even need two binaries as you suggest since Perl programs are distributed as source. (`perl` compiles them when it loads them, and even then, they are compiled to the same form on all systems.)

Comment: Thanks, But if I am not compiling it, then the user needs perl on thier system which is not what I like. I like a solution that acts as a *.exe on windows and then user needs to run it. The same on Mac.

Comment: Most macs already have perl installed but there isn't anything that will run on both without dependencys.

Comment: Well, most systems have JVMs, so distributing a .jar plus launcher scripts for each OS might do the trick, even if slapping Perl or Python on the Windows boxes is probably easier in the long run.

Comment: @amon: Java is no longer installed by default on OS X.